# Подключение к БД java EE

Tags: mysql, sql, java-ee, jsp

Хочу подключиться к БД в java EE, взять оттуда хотя бы одно имя из БД, но это не получается... Вот код в сервлете:

```
Connection grdCON = null;
    Statement grdST = null;
    ResultSet grdRS=null;
    String grdDB = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/graduate-work-db";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "paswrd";
    String msgDB=null;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        grdCON = DriverManager.getConnection(grdDB, user, password);
        grdST = grdCON.createStatement();
        grdRS = grdST.executeQuery("SELECT name FROM users;");
        if (grdRS.next()) {
        msgDB = grdRS.getString(1);
        request.setAttribute("message",msgDB);
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException excp){
        msgDB = excp.getMessage();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (grdRS!=null){
                grdRS.close();
            }
            if (grdST !=null){
                grdST.close();
            }
            if (grdCON!=null){
                grdCON.close();
            }

        }catch (SQLException excp){
            msgDB = excp.getMessage();
        }
    }
request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

После этого всего дела он вроде должен подключиться к БД взять оттуда `name` с `ID=5` но он не делает этого...
Что я делаю не так? Где ошибка? Вот `JSP` Где должен показаться данное имя...

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      Test
      <br>
      <br>
      <h1><%=request.getAttribute("message")%></h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

В теге `h1` пишется NULL... А по идее должно было быть мое имя из БД.

Comment: В какой строчке Вашего кода извлекается `name` из результата запроса?

Comment: @Sergey По идее он должен брать из БД этот `name` мое имя, и показать в теге h1, но оно не делает этого... Я только только изучаю это, поэтому столкнулся с этой проблемой

Comment: Он что силою мысли должен брать? Это Ваш код или чужой? Представляете что он делает в каждой строке, приведённого листинга?

Comment: @Sergey Хмм, этот код я написал смотря документацию) а так не особо понимаю :D :D Я только только учусь подключать БД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это не нужно в javaee:

```
Connection grdCON = null;
Statement grdST = null;
ResultSet grdRS=null;
String grdDB = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/graduate-work-db";
String user = "root";
String password = "paswrd";
String msgDB=null;
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    grdCON = DriverManager.getConnection(grdDB, user, password);
```

Делают примерно так:

```
public class GrdServlet extends ...
    Resource("jdbc/grdDS")     // сервер внедряет
    private DataSource grdDS;  // базу данных из своей конфигурации

    ...

    public void doGet(...) {
        Connection grdCON = grdDS.getConnection();
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

1) Драйвер jdbc должен быть помещен в папку общих библиотек сервера.
2) На сервере приложение должна быть создана конфигурация базы данных.
В этой конфигурации указывается драйвер, сервер базы данных, имя базы данных, логин (всё что ранее пытались делать в программе выносится в конфигурацию сервера).
3) Конфигурации назначается имя JNDI `java:/jdbc/grdDS` (должно совпадать с `Resource("jdbc/grdDS")`).

Папка библиотек, конфигурация и именование ресурсов - это всё специфично для каждого сервера.

Часто это можно сделать через web-морду сервера.

Это самый простейший вариант (со своими недостатками, которых в большинстве случаев на сам деле и нет).

Comment: Вооо сработало))) Спасибо :))) Спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(grdRS.next()){
    msgDB = grdRS.toString();
    String username  = rs.getString("name");
    }
```

Comment: Неа, делал я так, не помогало... Все время пишет в теге `h1` NULL

Comment: @KryTer_NexT сколько строчек в базе? скинь скрин запроса, пожалуйста.

Comment: В базе всего 4 строки, если ввести `SELECT * FROM users;` будет 4 человека, с ID=4,5,6,7... А если `SELECT name FROM users;` то просто 4 имени) Это тестовая база, я новичок, впервые подключаю БД...

Comment: @KryTer_NexT а когда дебажишься, то каждый раз показывает NULL?

Comment: @senor Теперь вообще пишет что `JDBC` не найден... Как исправить? Я вроде его подключал не? xDD Илииии.......

Comment: @KryTer_NexT проверь classPath и dependecy

Comment: Я бы с радостью, ноо как это сделать? :D Где его найти?

Comment: @KryTer_NexT драйвер jdbc надо разместить в папке общих библиотек сервера. У каждого сервера своя. или попробуйте в папку WEB-INF\lib Вашего приложения. А вообще в javaee подключение к бд делается по-другому

Comment: @SeniorAutomator Вот мне нужно именно для JavaEE, так в отдельном Maven проекте делал, вроде как-то работало, тут че-то не то(